# Inserting SQLite primary key in python

Tags: python, sqlite

I am trying to do a SQLite insert from my python script.

I am getting an error:

```
table history has 4 columns but 3 values were supplied
```

The reason there is 3 not 4, is that the first one is my ID. I assumed that as i declared it as a primary key it would auto-increment the value. How do I go about inserting the ID

.py:

```
c.execute("INSERT INTO history VALUES (?,?,?)", (q[0],t,in))
```

.db

```
CREATE TABLE history (id integer primary key, employeeID integer, time datetime, inout varchar);
```

Comment: `(q[0],t,in)` Wouldn't this give a parse error, as `in` is a keyword?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You either have to provide values for *all* columns, or name the columns you are inserting into explicitly. SQLite will not go and guess what columns you provided values for, you need to be explicit about them.

You can use a `NULL` to have SQLite insert an auto-generated id for you:

```
c.execute("INSERT INTO history VALUES (NULL,?,?,?)", (q[0],t,in))
```

or you can name the 3 columns you are inserting into explicitly:

```
c.execute("INSERT INTO history (employeeID, time, inout) VALUES (?,?,?)", (q[0],t,in))
```

Comment: Is `NULL` case-sensitive here?

Comment: @AnttiHaapala: there are many bad ideas when it comes to interop. The better idea is to use SQLAlchemy if interop is important.